# Method definition as result of function call in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Here's a sample piece of JS for Knockout:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
}
```

In case you're unfamiliar with KO, each field on `AppViewModel` becomes a function (i.e. `ko.observable` and `ko.computed` each return a function. Also note that `fullName` depends on both functions.

How can I rewrite this to ClojureScript?

One thing to try is:

```
(deftype AppViewModel [firstName lastName]
  Object
  (fullName [this] (.computed js/ko (str (firstName) " " (lastName)))))

(defn my-model [first last]
  (AppViewModel. 
    (.observable js/ko "Bob") 
    (.observable js/ko "Smith")))
```

It doesn't work though, since `fullName` becomes a function that calls `ko.computed`. That is, it compiles to:

```
my_namespace.AppViewModel.prototype.fullName = function() {
  return ko.computed([cljs.core.str(this.firstName.call(null)), cljs.core.str(" "), cljs.core.str(this.lastName.call(null))].join(""))
};
```

How can I deal with it in ClojureScript?

Again, note the dependency of `fullName` on `this` and `firstName`/`lastName`.

Comment: Note that you're currently only passing one string parameter to `.computed`. In your JavaScript example you pass a function and a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defn my-model [first last]
  (let [fname (.observable js/ko first)
        lname (.observable js/ko last)
        full-name (.computed js/ko #(str (fname) " " (lname)))] 
        (js-obj "firstName" fname
                "lastName" lname
                "fullName" full-name)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Riffing on @Ankur's answer, seems like you could also do the following:

```
  (deftype AppViewModel [firstName lastName fullName])

  (defn my-model [first last]
    (AppViewModel. 
      (.observable js/ko "Bob") 
      (.observable js/ko "Smith")
      (.computed js/ko (str (firstName) " " (lastName)))))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! However, it compiles to: https://gist.github.com/konrad-garus/4733108 - "this" is lost, refers to "global" firstName and lastName...